# handle ANSI(color/formatting) charecters from process in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, subprocess

I have a problem with ANSI

let say i have this
`b'\x1b[38;2;22;198;12mhay\x1b[0m\r\n'`

so how do I remove unwanted chars

code

```py
>>> sub = subprocess.run(["python","-c","import ColorCraft;ColorCraft.print('hay')"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> sub.stdout
b'\x1b[38;2;22;198;12mhay\x1b[0m\r\n'
```

**used modules**

- [ColorCraft](https://pypi.org/project/CrafterColor/)
- [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: I assume by "unwanted chars" you mean the ANSI escape sequences? Then please open your favorite search engine and search for e.g. `python how to remove ansi escape sequences from string`. What results do you get? Do they help you? If not, then what problems do you have with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexes to remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in Python. Simply substitute the escape sequences with an empty string using re.sub(). The regex you can use for removing ANSI escape sequences is: '(\x9B|\x1B[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]'.

For example,

```py
import re
def escape_ansi(line):
    ansi_escape =re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', line)
print (escape_ansi(line = '\u001b[0;35mSomeText\u001b[0m\u001b[0;36m172.18.0.2\u001b[0m'))
```

This will give the output:

```
SomeText172.18.0.2
```

**resources**

- [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-remove-the-ANSI-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)